# Android 11 cannot retrieve files created be using MediaStore after the app re-installs

Tags: android, mediastore

After the app is uninstalled and reinstalled its not possible to read existing files on android 11 and higher versions

I tried Media store api to store all my downloaded pdf files to external storage before downloading a file I am checking whether Uri exists, if exists reading a file from external storage and I am starting the intent to show the downloaded file, if file doesn't exists then I am downloading a file.
Everything is working fine but if application is uninstalled and re-installed every time file is getting download instead of reading a file from external storage and starting an intent

My question is its not possible to read existing files on android 11 and higher versions once the app is uninstalled and reinstalled

Comment: As you know on Android 11+ devices an app will inly 'see' its own files and some media files. Reinstall means to be a different app.

Comment: @blackapps But this is not happening in android 10 and below versions